# Shall we use multiple combine reducers?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have three reducers

- Home
- Listing
- Detail

I have one combine reducer for above three. But I want to divide project structure into multiple reducers. Is it a good practice to have multiple combine reducer in the project?

Comment: the best way to go.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can have multiple `combineReducers` in your App, You can at the top level combine reducers `Home , Listing and Detail`  and even split each individual reducers into multiple and combine them into one.

According to the Redux **[docs](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#tips)**:

> You may call `combineReducers` at any level of the reducer hierarchy.
>   It doesn't have to happen at the top. In fact you may use it again to
>   split the child reducers that get too complicated into independent
>   grandchildren, and so on.

Some more description about [`combineReducer`](http://redux.js.org/docs/api/combineReducers.html#combinereducersreducers):

> As your app grows more complex, you'll want to split your reducing
>   function into separate functions, each managing independent parts of
>   the state.
>
> The `combineReducers` helper function turns an object whose values are
>   different reducing functions into a single reducing function you can
>   pass to `createStore`.
>
> The resulting reducer calls every child reducer, and gathers their
>   results into a single state object. The shape of the state object
>   matches the keys of the passed reducers.

Comment: I will add that `combineReducers` is just a beginning. In a growing app, you will probably want to make your own reducers combinator function that allows you for exemple to do the same thing as `combineReducers` but with Imutable.js data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can combine multi reducer and use it as one store,

1. Firstly, you should import all reducers in a new file. then, combine all reducers with combine-reducer technics,like this:

   import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
   import {Home,Listing,Detail} from '*/**';

   const rootReducer = combineReducers({
   Home,
   Listing,
   Detail
   })

   export default rootReducer
2. Secondly, import the new file in Store file and create your store with combined-reducer

   import { createStore } from 'redux'
   import rootReducer from '*/combinestores'

   const store = createStore(rootReducer)
   console.log(store.getState())*optinal*

   export default store
3. In the end, in your container you can use your store like this :
   (but before it, you should be sure send store as props to Containers)

   const mapStateToProps = state => {

   ```
    return{
       *name of your var* :  state.Home.*,
       *name of your var* :  state.Detail.*  /*then you can use this var as props anywhere you need*/
    }
   ```

   }

   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
   return{

   ```
        *name of your var* : () => dispatch ( *name of your func*()),
        *name of your var* : () => dispatch ( *name of your func*())


    }
   ```

   }

   export default connect(mapStateToProps,mapDispatchToProps)(*name of func*);